# Getting data from submitted form

Tags: forms

I am trying to get data from a submitted form - as far as I can tell, data is being passed correctly, but I want to look at and manipulate it.

I'm trying to `print_r()` it with no success - because it happens after form submission and it isn't on the previous page.

This is my submit function so far:

```
function multi_reg_pagecreate_submit($form, &$form_state) {

$form_state['values']['multi_reg_checkbox'];

}
```

The checkboxes are generated on the page `/multiple-registration`, but I have no way of checking my variables once this page is submitted.

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [devel module](http://drupal.org/project/devel) will help a lot. It provides a `dpm()` function which is similar to `print_r()` but provides you with a nested array of data to look through in Drupal's messages area.

You're correct in that `$form_state['values']` holds the user input, but since the submit handler will return back to the previous page automatically, you're better off doing something like this in your `_validate()` handler (or throwing a `dpm()` in your submit handler if you don't mind that running). This will let you debug things quickly and then submit when you're ready for it:

```
<?php
function my_form($form, &$form_state) {
  // Build out the $form.
}

function my_form_validate(&$form, &$form_state) {
  dpm($form_state['values');
  form_error($form, "Debugging the form.");
}

function my_form_submit(&$form, &$form_state) {
  // Perform your submit functionality here.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check your variables by printing them with [drupal_set_message()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/function/drupal_set_message/7).

```
function multi_reg_pagecreate_submit($form, &$form_state) {
  drupal_set_message('<pre>' . print_r($form_state['values'], true) . '</pre>');
}
```

Alternatively, you can use [debug()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/debug/7)

```
debug($form_state['values'], 'Debugging the form', TRUE);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure of this, and I'm not a FAPI expert by any stretch but something like:

`$form_state['input']` might be useful.